# How to solve android studio latest version using proguard apk?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-proguard, android-developer-api

1. build.gradle (Project)

   ```
   buildscript {
       ext.support_version = '27.0.3'
       ext.play_service_version = '11.8.0'
       repositories {
           jcenter()
           maven {
               url 'https://maven.google.com/'
           }
           google()
       }
       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha07'
           classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
           classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0'
       }
   }
   allprojects {
       repositories {
           jcenter()
       }
   }
   allprojects {
       repositories {
           jcenter()
           google()
           maven {
               url 'https://maven.google.com/'
           }
       }
   }
   task clean(type: Delete) {
       delete rootProject.buildDir
   }
   ```
2. build.gradle (app)

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   android {
       compileSdkVersion 27
       defaultConfig {
           applicationId "xxx.com.xxooking"
           minSdkVersion 14
           targetSdkVersion 25
           versionCode 3
           versionName "0.4"
           testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
           multiDexEnabled true
       }
       buildTypes {
           release {
               minifyEnabled true
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           }
       }
       lintOptions {
           checkReleaseBuilds false
       }
   }
   dependencies {
       implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
           exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
       })
       implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
       implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
       implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
       implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
       implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
       implementation 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'
       implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0'
       implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
       implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
       implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0'
       implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
       implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
       implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
       implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
       implementation 'com.applozic.communication.uiwidget:mobicomkitui:4.85'
       testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
       androidTestImplementation('com.android.support:design:27.0.0') {
           exclude module: "com.android.support:design"
       }
   }
   ```
3. Proguard-rules-pro

   ```
   -dontusemixedcaseclassnames
   -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
   -verbose
   ```

**Error:**

```
//// com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zza  
retrofit.RxSupport$1: can't find superclass or interface rx.Observable$OnSubscribe
retrofit.client.OkClient$1: can't find superclass or interface com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody
com.google.firebase.iid.zzb: can't find referenced method 'MessengerCompat(android.os.Handler)' in program class com.google.android.gms.iid.MessengerCompat
com.google.firebase.iid.zzb: can't find referenced method 'android.os.IBinder getBinder()' in program class com.google.android.gms.iid.MessengerCompat
com.google.firebase.iid.zzb$1: can't find referenced method 'int zzc(android.os.Message)' in program class com.google.android.gms.iid.MessengerCompat
com.google.firebase.iid.zzh: can't find referenced method 'java.io.File getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)' in program class com.google.android.gms.common.util.zzw
com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zza
com.google.firebase.messaging.zza: can't find referenced method 'boolean zzyH()' in program class com.google.android.gms.common.util.zzs
com.google.firebase.messaging.zzb: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement
com.google.firebase.messaging.zzb: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$zza
com.google.firebase.messaging.zzb: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$zze
com.google.firebase.messaging.zzb: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$zzg
com.google.firebase.messaging.zzb: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement
com.google.firebase.messaging.zzc: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zzb
com.google.firebase.messaging.zzc: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zzb$zza
com.google.firebase.messaging.zzc: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zzc
com.google.firebase.messaging.zzc: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zzb
com.google.firebase.messaging.zzc: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zzb$zza
com.google.firebase.messaging.zzc: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zzc
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl$Builder
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Call
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl$Builder
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Call
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl$Builder
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
okio.DeflaterSink: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
retrofit.RestMethodInfo$RxSupport: can't find referenced class rx.Observable
retrofit.RxSupport: can't find referenced class rx.Observable
retrofit.RxSupport: can't find referenced class rx.Observable$OnSubscribe
retrofit.RxSupport: can't find referenced class rx.Observable
retrofit.RxSupport: can't find referenced class rx.Subscriber
retrofit.RxSupport$1: can't find referenced class rx.subscriptions.Subscriptions
retrofit.RxSupport$1: can't find referenced class rx.Subscriber
retrofit.RxSupport$1: can't find referenced class rx.Observable$OnSubscribe
retrofit.RxSupport$1: can't find referenced class rx.subscriptions.Subscriptions
retrofit.RxSupport$1: can't find referenced class rx.Observable
retrofit.RxSupport$1: can't find referenced class rx.Subscriber
retrofit.RxSupport$1: can't find referenced class rx.Observable$OnSubscribe
retrofit.RxSupport$2: can't find referenced class rx.Subscriber
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceFactory
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchService
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPHeader
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPHeader
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPHeader
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceFactory
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchService
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchService
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchService
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchService
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchService
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPHeader
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPHeader
retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Call
retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request
retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType
retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Headers
retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Call
retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request
retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType
retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Headers
retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request
retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody
retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType
retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Headers
retrofit.client.OkClient$1: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody
retrofit.client.OkClient$1: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType
retrofit.client.OkClient$2: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
retrofit.client.OkClient$2: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType
retrofit.client.OkClient$2: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
retrofit.client.OkClient$2: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType
retrofit.client.OkClient$2: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
retrofit.client.OkClient$2: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType
retrofit.client.OkClient$2: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
retrofit.client.OkClient$2: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType
retrofit2.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
there were 223 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
```

**Problem:**

First proguard time show Lint related error  so me add following line in build.gradle(app) file.

After proguard time show all libraries warning message and not proguard apk (without proguard apk working good)

Comment: I've fixed the formatting. But I still don't understand your problem description. Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: normally run time apk will be generate no problem. but proguard  (generate apk) time apk not generated. show's above error. how to solve this issue?

Comment: normally run time apk will be generate no problem. but proguard  (generate apk) time apk not generated. show's above error but before update android studio i used android-studio v2.2 that time proguard apk generated, after update android-studio proguard apk generate failed. how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Changes apply both files

> build.gradle (project)

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

/// > 2) Build.gradle (app)
    change target sdk version 27
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'